# Why is question mark put immediately after the last letter

Tags: punctuation, question-marks

I have noticed that the sentence: "Where did you go?" is marked grammatically incorrect my some websites and there should not be a space between the 'go' and **'?'**

I have two questions

1. Is putting a **?** with a space grammatically incorrect
2. Why such a rule is there?

Comment: An excellent answer [here at English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark)

Comment: correction: Why is there a question mark etc.

Comment: A related question: is this practice (putting a space between the last word and the punctuation mark) considered correct in *any* language?  I feel like I see it done a lot by non-native speakers of English, but very rarely by native speakers, suggesting this might be a carryover from another language's style.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is **in**correct to add a space before the question mark. **All** punctuation (question/exclamation/quotation marks, commas, periods, colons/semicolons, closing parentheses) goes immediately after a word with no spaces.

It used to be proper to put one space before and two spaces after a colon :  like this, but that is not done anymore.

The "rule" is there because that is how punctuation works and is used in English. I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for here.

Comment: Short answer: 1. Yes 2. Because.

Answer (score 0):

Punctuation, can. be - grammatically, incorrect ! but the spacing of punctuation is simply a matter of usage. Maybe people might have decided to use a space before a question mark, but they didn't. Question marks immediately follow the final letter or number.